# Fullscreen background Image resize

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I'm trying to set a background image to fullscreen, and **on window resize the image doesn't change actuall pixel size, but get's smaller (crop-like)**.

This is what I mean: (Try to resize window and notice that the picture gets smaller or larger but doesn't pixelate) http://jsfiddle.net/G7Qc4/

Now, the above works because of the image is a background of a div and I've set:

`background-position: center top;`

If it was just plain `<img>` it doesn't work which my question is how can I make it work? If there is any way around?

I am using the nivoSlider which doesn't accept div's for image's so I will have to use `<img>`.

Thanks alot

Comment: You'd have to use the background-size CSS property, which is only supported in very recent versions of most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to use an actual  tag as a background instead of background-image.

Here is my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/ttZeM/

It requires knowing the dimensions of the background image.

There is a div holding the background which is absolutely positioned, the site content is absolutely positioned on top of it.

To center the background image, I moved it -500px to the left, which is half it's width. It is inside of a div that is 0px wide, being centered with `position:absolute; left:50%` a strange technique, but it works if you know the image size.

Also note that the bg_wrap div has overflow:hidden; and width:100%; this means you won't see scrollbars off the edges of the screen.

I hope this is what you were after!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with CSS3 (`background-size: cover`), like so: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/Kq3pa/